# What does the zero set of $x_i$ mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> If $f\in S$ is a linear homogeneous polynomial, then the zero set of $f$ is called  hyperplane. In particuar we denote the zero set of $x_i$ by $H_i$, for $i=0,1,2,\dots,n $. Let $U_i$ be the open set $P^n-H_i$.

Here $S$ is the polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. What does zero set of $x_i$ mean?

Comment: Note that $x_i$ is also a linear homogeneous polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

It is the set of all points $(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ such that $x_i=0$.  In this case the function $f$ is defined by $f(x_0,\dots,x_n)=x_i$.

Comment: Small comment: Judging from the OP's question, she's looking at projective geometry, in which case your answer is still correct, but the example is not quite.  If we have three variables, you get the projective line of points $[x,y,0]$ where $x$ and $y$ are not both $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed the $P^n$.